# Heading, followed by code: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code

Tags: support, bug, markdown, error-message, not-properly-formatted-as-code

A few moments ago I encountered a pretty annoying bug with the code detection and the preview-function, when I wanted to post an answer. While the preview looked like this:

> ### *Some Title*
>
> ```
> code that was below the title
> ```
>
> *text explaining the code*

using this text in my answer:

```
*Some Title*
--
    code that was below the title
*text explaining the code*
```

It kept refusing to post the answer and telling me:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code ...

Looking at the preview, everything looks fine and formatted as it should be.

What am I missing that causes this error and how should I resolve this error?

Comment: You need an empty line before a code block, always.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's almost true. You don't need a blank line before the code block, if the code is the first line in the post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It took me half an hour to understand, that it still **need an empty line** below the title 
(more accurate: *in front of the code*)

```
*Some Title*
--

    code that was below the title
*text explaining the code*
```

I think in this case, the preview is very missleading, since I scrolled through it wondering where to find unformated code, while everything was displayed fine.

Comment: Right, so there is an issue with the preview not handling this case properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a better way to report such an issue? I thought meta would be something like the general platform to talk about stackoverflow and its features.?

Comment: This is the right place.

Comment: You could update the question to make it explicit how the preview still shows the code  block correctly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I gave it a try, but I'm not that confident with my language skills. Hope this is more satisfying now.

Comment: I remember having this same bug when I was a beginner in StackOverflow. I thought I was doing something wrong. I left the code unformatted and someone else edited it afterwards. It's good to finally know the reason why :) (2 years later)