# How to properly format the code in a question if I’m visually impaired?

Tags: support, code-formatting, accessibility

The question form always refuses the code I post because it is not formatted properly. The problem is that I am almost blind (visus 0.01 %) and have to use an 8× magnifier to see anything at all. If there are any spacings/indentation missing I cannot make them out (and I don't have anyone in my life who could help me). What can I do?

Comment: Indentation isn’t necessarily needed if you use three backticks (`\`\`\``) before and after your code, in their own lines, with a blank line before the first and a blank line after the last triplet of backticks. See [Implement `\`\`\``-style (fenced) Markdown code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322000/289905).

Comment: I honestly can't wait for code fences to become the default option on [main].

Comment: you ca use scree reader and braille all elements have an alt text as far as i can see, so that shouldn't be a problem. besides there a lot of nice peolple who will fix that for you if you explain that you dificulties

Comment: @nbk the problem is that there is nothing to fix because they can't get past that stupid SE validation. They can't post.

Comment: have you a screenshot, i have no validation.

Comment: @nbk People with accounts that have no reputation are not subject to the same set of rules as you are.

Comment: isn't it possible to just paste, then mark code and use CTRL+K ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre from the few answers I wrote on trying to support / resolve these kind of errors, I found it notoriously difficult. And I'm not blind, nor were the askers ...

Comment: pasting all question as indented code doesn't work either, the system wants a ratio of non-code text. That can be an issue here obviously. But what about pasting the code _without formatting_ explaining that you can't do it, and let others do it for you? I don't think code as text is blocked by the system.

Comment: For the record, the code in [your most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67393419/208273) looked well-formatted to me.  I moved it into a runnable HTML snippet to make it easier to reproduce your issues, but that's not required: the way you posted that was correct.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There was a block if the system detects a lot of text that it thinks looks like unformatted code but I don't know if it's still in use: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363421/heading-followed-by-code-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properl

Answer (score 9):

Try to get your question formatted enough to get through the automated filter, and if you don’t get it exactly right someone here can edit it the rest of the way.

Code fences are your best option for code. Simply add new lines (hit “enter” or “return” twice or so), then type three backticks ```` ``` ```` or three tildes (`~~~`). Hit enter again and then paste your code. Lastly, close the code block with another new line of three backticks or tildes, whatever you used to open the block.

Here’s what it should be like, notice the fact that the fences are on their own lines:

````
```
Code here!
```
````

Hopefully, this makes sense and it helps you. If not, I suggest [editing your meta question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/407405/edit) to mention what error you’re getting (there is also an "edit" link under your post you can use).

Comment: I'd suggest (exceptionnally) to add something like "sorry about the formatting, my vision is pretty bad" and people will edit the post to remove this message & will fix the indentation _without downvoting_

Comment: But @Jean-FrançoisFabre the problem is that they don't get that far, probably because they missed a white line, have a single weird character in the first paragraph, have included a screenshot where the inserted reference isn't separated from the code / text, you name it. The point isn't that we are not wiling to help, the problem is, they don't get the bare minimum past some archaic / overly eager validation in the Post logic of SE. This site is pretty stoopid for users with visual disabilities. Not inclusive at all.

Comment: Success! https://stackoverflow.com/q/67393419/6083675

Answer (score -11):

A potential option would be to use a formatter like Prettier in your code editor and then paste the formatted code into Stack Overflow, usually helps my formatting issues!

Comment: Why is this downvoted so heavily? I use the same method all the time. For complex code, I paste it into my favorite editor (Visual Studio or notepad++) let it format for me and then paste it back.

Comment: really not sure myself why everyone has taken such issue with this approach, would be keen to hear some thoughts on it!

Comment: Contextually this seems like the wrong place to make this suggestion, since we're talking about someone who is nearly blind. Copy/pasting stuff between applications just doesn't seem like the way to go.