# The Stack Snippets feature does not meet accessibility guidelines, and the editor is confusing with a keyboard

Tags: bug, editor, accessibility

It's hard to navigate the posting process while only using a keyboard, and it's impossible if you're trying to use a Stack Snippet. Note: Not only do visually impaired users rely on the keyboard to navigate, so do those with regular sight who may have a motor impairment that prevents them from using a mouse.

### Stack Snippets

I wanted to update my answer to [How to properly format the code in a question if I’m visually impaired?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407405/6083675) with a keyboard solution for Stack Snippets, but there's no way I can find for a keyboard user to do use Stack Snippets. I'm able to press <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, but my focus is still on the page behind that.

I looked at the user's questions and saw that their codeblocks got edited into Stack Snippets (by well-meaning users, I know). So what are they supposed to do if they want to edit? It's very confusing for anyone who's not an advanced user.

If you do somehow get your cursor into one of the code fields, then the only way out is hitting <kbd>escape</kbd> and losing all your progress, since hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> indents instead of leaving the field.

### Key Combos

But I'm not sure how you would figure out you need to do <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, or any key combo for that matter. (I wonder if this has anything to do with why we needed a question about how to format code in the first place.)

My tab focus goes: title field, body field, tags field (then the options in the dropdown, which annoyingly block the screen unless you tab back and hit escape), submit button, finally getting to the top bar, then to all the UI elements that were skipped over that I thought just wouldn't ever get focus (similar questions, "answer your own question", "Discard" draft), but the only item near the toolbar to be focusable or do anything is "more" (which is [ambiguous link text](https://blog.pope.tech/2018/07/26/why-ambiguous-links-are-problematic/), another accessibility problem), and you can only see this if formatting tips are shown, since you can't focus on "Show/Hide formatting tips" if they're not. This tab sequence is confusing and exactly why my accessibility tools say to not use a positive tabindex (as is happening here).

While it doesn't make sense to be able to activate any of the toolbar functions with the keyboard other than undo/redo (you're no longer in the editor, so there's nothing obvious to apply formatting to), it would make sense to be able to do something with them. The best option I can think of is to be able to tab there but trying to use the buttons would tell you (both visually and in the screenreader, if it's not already there) the correct shortcut: "Format as code: Control + K on highlighted text".

Comment: Makes me realize they don't call `preventDefault()` when triggering these shortcuts, on my Firefox control + M does mute the Tab.

Comment: Worth noting also that StackSnippets editor still "does not support touch devices". If some work is made in this area it would be great it handles this too.

Comment: as an extra note - it is not uncommon for those with normal sight and no impairments to rely on the keyboard exclusively for various reasons. That said, it is unlikely, methinks, that the request will be actioned any time soon - what was the last time *any* work was done on the snippets feature?

Comment: The latest version of jQuery available is 3.3.1. The latest version of AngularJS is 1.7.5 (and let's not even mention Angular). The console can't handle Maps or Sets and those were introduced 6+ years ago. No Storage API support... I'd laugh at this [bug] but it really makes me want to cry. They should just license the tech behind vscode.dev and call it a day :) <-- that means I'm kidding.

Comment: There are [Years worth of Snippet bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets) and upgrade requests that have been completely ignored by the company. Good luck getting this feature enabled